# Why don't pipe organs have diaphragm stops?

Tags: organ

Why don't pipe organs have stops operating by disk-shaped diaphragms like this?

[image: Diagram of disk-shaped diaphragm stop]

Comment: Why would they? Explaining the motivations of this question would enhance it a lot!

Comment: @JonathanDahlin Could you mention what this diagram is from? (And, for all I know, some organs *do* have them; do you know that they don't?)

Comment: Not making people click through to an external link would help too… all that URL for a simple drawing.

Comment: @AndyBonner that looks like an air horn of the sort one might find on a boat or a train.  I'm sure there's a theater organ somewhere that has some.

Comment: For one thing, unlike an air horn, the air in a pipe organ is compressed, but not at high PSI, so the volume of the air is important.  From the looks of it a diaphragm doesn't have much of a cross-section to allow the air through.